# bar chart onclick get specific index

Tags: javascript, chart.js

js` to display the bar chart and each part of bar chart has multiple bars. so when i click the bars i need the specific index with in it.please help me fix it and check the fiddle.

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbdqxfzL/16/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=rbdqxfzL)

Comment: The value of the bar? or what?

Comment: hi aifrim each month has two bars so i need index of specific bar in specific month.